# Looping set state react + firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a user profile page for my app, for this page I'm trying to get a doc with some user information from firestore, and populate fields that the user can click on and to change. When I added the `setTags` function to the db call below, it resulted in an infinite loop. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it? I'm very new to using react hooks.

```
const UserProfile = ({history}) => {
        const description = useRef('');
        const name = useRef('');
        const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
        let [tags, setTags] = useState('');
        let uData;
        db.collection('Users').doc(currentUser.uid).get().then(doc => {
            console.log("checking db")
            console.log(doc.data())
            uData = doc.data();
            description.current = uData.description;
            name.current = uData.name
            setTags(uData.tags)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional components are run on every render. That means that on every rerender, you open the database to search for the current user, then set the tags. Crucially, updating the state always causes a rerender! This is a core feature of React that allows implicit updating and is one of the main reasons to use React in the first place.

If you want something to be run only once, you can still do that, but you need to simulate `componentDidMount()` from a class component. So, you can use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```js
// Add this import in
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const UserProfile = ({history}) => {
    const description = useRef('');
    const name = useRef('');
    const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
    let [tags, setTags] = useState('');
    let uData;
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('Users').doc(currentUser.uid).get().then(doc => {
            console.log("checking db")
            console.log(doc.data())
            uData = doc.data();
            description.current = uData.description;
            name.current = uData.name
            setTags(uData.tags)
        })
    }, []); // Empty dependency list means this will only run on first render
}
```